# How to see who is listening scroll event on google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, listener

I have a magento project and some theme script inside listens for scroll and changes classes after some pixels scrolled down. Is there are any way to find this listener by just finding who is listening to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit F12 to open Dev Tools ( CMD + ALT + I on mac )
2. Click the Sources tab On right-hand side
3. Look for "Event Listener Breakpoints" ( on the right side )
4. Select Control -> Scroll or Mouse

Comment: I tried this method but the thing is when I select to listen for scroll it just gets me comressed jquery text which is not useful. http://i.imgur.com/La4a2wo.png

Comment: Maybe a tool like this is what you mean ? http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: Yes but it only reacts to onclick but not onscroll